# Problems with an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I need help with an sql table.

The table contains the following columns:

EventID, PersonID, EventType, EventTime(datetime), and a few other less significant columns.

Lets say that the two main event types are opening a door and closing a door.

I need the time duration(in seconds) between the same person opening a door and closing it or  him opening a door and opening another one.(this of course allows sequences of simply opening doors)

Just to be clear if person 1 opened a door and person 2 closed a door no rows should be returned from the query.

I would like for it to be efficient but that isn't a must.

I'm using the 2008 SQL microsoft server(SQLEXPRESS)

Here is an example of a table:

```
EventID | PersonID | EventType | EventDate                | PreviousDoor | CurrentDoor
   1    |    1     |    1      | 12/10/2010 12:00:01.024  |      0       |     23
   2    |    1     |    2      | 12/10/2010 12:05:40.758  |      23      |     0
   3    |    2     |    1      | 12/10/2010 12:12:05.347  |      0       |     12
   4    |    1     |    1      | 12/10/2010 12:50:12.142  |      0       |     23
   5    |    2     |    2      | 12/10/2010 13:00:06.468  |      12      |     23
   6    |    3     |    1      | 13/10/2010 13:00:06.468  |      0       |     23
```

EventType: 1(Opened door), 2(Closed door)

Result should be:

```
EventID | PersonID | EventType | EventDate                | SecondsDifference
   1    |    1     |    1      | 12/10/2010 12:00:01.024  | 339
   3    |    2     |    1      | 12/10/2010 12:12:05.347  | 2881
```

I could really use your guys help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will using `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION` help?
I'm not sure if the following is a legal SQL statement so please consider it as semi pseudo code.

```
SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY EventTime) AS RowNumber,
  datediff(seconds, t2.EventTime, t1.EventTime) AS SecondsDiff
FROM Events t1 
  INNER JOIN 
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY EventTime) AS RowNumber 
    From Events t2 
  ON t1.RowNumber + 1 = t2.RowNumber 
    AND t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID AND t1.EventType = 1 
    AND (t2.EventType = 1 OR t2.EventType = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
    SELECT          p1.EventID,
                    p1.PersonID,
                    p1.EventType,
                    p1.EventDate,
                    DATEDIFF(SECOND, p1.EventDate, p2.EventDate) AS SecondsDifference
    FROM            [Event] p1
    LEFT JOIN       [Event] p2  --Left join to self returning only closed door events
    ON              p2.PersonID = p1.PersonID
    AND             p2.EventType = 2 -- Closed Door
    AND             p1.EventID < p2.EventID --We don't want to bring back events that happened before the next event
    WHERE           p2.EventID IS NOT NULL --We don't want to show any people that have not closed a door
```

Comment: I suggest turning the LEFT JOIN into an inner JOIN (making the `p2.EventID IS NOT NULL` redundant)  - OP only wants paired open/close events - and adding a `WHERE p1.EventType = 1` condition.

Comment: @KevRitchie why `LEFT JOIN`? and.. You need to use the `CurrentDoor` and `PreviousDoor` for a better result :)

Comment: @MarkBannister exactly! just what I did :)

Comment: Nice suggestions.  I think I'm too used to typing LEFT JOIN :S.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: GMTA - unfortunately not for me on a Friday ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys but won't the query result in every closed door event to be diffed against every open door event(which precedes it)? Each opened door event should be paired with a single open or close door event...

Comment: Doesn't @aF. solution give you what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select t1.EventID, t1.PersonID, t1.EventType, t1.EventDate, datediff(second, t1.EventDate, t2.EventDate) as 'SecondsDifference'
from [Event] t1
inner join [Event] t2 on t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID and t2.EventType = 2 and t2.PreviousDoor = t2.CurrentDoor and t2.EventID < t1.EventID
where t1.EventType = 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure the query provides the correct result, please note that it is possible for two open door events to be paired together. Also what if I open and then close door 1 and open and close it again(4 events overall) won't the first event be also paired with last event?(I might be wrong, a bit rusty on sql)